# If a medic claims on a medical report that he is a fellow of a specialist medical college when he no longer is, what kind of wrong is committed?

Tags: medical

If a medic claims on a medical report that he is a fellow of a specialist medical college, but actually he isn't, because his membership lapsed many years ago, is he committing an actionable wrong against the college, or against the American Medical Association, or indeed against any party other than the patient?

Comment: Trademark violation against the owner of the college, likely a professional sanction issue, and misrepresentation to to the readers of the report?